# Optimize sql query to speed up a search which currently takes around 85 seconds

Tags: mysql, search, optimization

I have a database with the records near about 2.7 milion . I need to fetch records from that for that i am using the below query

for result

```
SELECT r3.original_image_title,r3.uuid,r3.original_image_URL FROM `image_attributes` AS r1 INNER JOIN `filenames` as r3 WHERE r1.`uuid` = r3.`uuid` and r3.`status` = 1 and r1.status=1 and (r1.`attribute_name` like "QuvenzhanÃ© Wallis%" or r3.original_image_URL like "QuvenzhanÃ© Wallis%") group by r3.`uuid` limit 0,20
```

for total count

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(r1.`uuid`)) as count FROM `image_attributes` AS r1 INNER JOIN `filenames` as r3 WHERE r1.`uuid` = r3.`uuid` and r3.`status` = 1 and r1.status=1 and (r1.`attribute_name` like "QuvenzhanÃ© Wallis%" or r3.original_image_URL like "QuvenzhanÃ© Wallis%")
```

table structures are as below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `image_attributes` (
  `index` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attribute_name` text NOT NULL,
  `attribute_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`index`),
  KEY `attribute_type` (`attribute_type`),
  KEY `uuid` (`uuid`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `attribute_name` (`attribute_name`(50))
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2730431 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `filenames` (
  `index` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `original_image_title` text NOT NULL,
  `original_image_URL` text NOT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`index`),
  KEY `uuid` (`uuid`),
  KEY `original_image_URL` (`original_image_URL`(50))
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=591967 ;
```

please suggest me how can i optimize the queries to make the search result faster

Comment: I am sure the OR condition is killing the query , let me do some optimization test on my local server, will come back after this.

Comment: You should use [FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) instead of your second query.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is SQL optimization and is more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: interesting the explain looks to be giving nice result, well I am doing with a small set of data, could you please run `explain your query` and share the result in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to you a book called ['High Performance MySql'](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do?sortby=publicationDate). There is a section called Optimize databases and queries, or something like that.